# Low quality with Glide

Tags: android, imageview, android-glide

When I use `Glide` to put and image inside an `ImageView` and then I "zoom in" (with a function that I bound to my `ImageView`), I see that the image has a low quality.

I already read `Glide` documentation but I'm not able to solve the problem.

Note: I use `Glide` inside a `ViewPager`.

This is what I did following the documentation

```
  Glide
        .with(context)
        .loadFromMediaStore(uri)
        .dontAnimate()
        .diskCacheStrategy(DiskCacheStrategy.SOURCE)
        .into(imageView);
```

This is the Manifest.xml

```
<manifest ...>
    <application...>
        <meta-data android:name="come.package.glide.MyGlideConfiguration"
            android:value="GlideModule"/>
    </application>
</manifest >
```

This is my GlideConfiguration

```
public class GlideConfiguration implements GlideModule {
    @Override
    public void applyOptions(Context context, GlideBuilder builder) {
        // Apply options to the builder here.
        builder.setDecodeFormat(DecodeFormat.PREFER_ARGB_8888);
    }

    @Override
    public void registerComponents(Context context, Glide glide) {
        // register ModelLoaders here.
    }
}
```

I also tried doing just

```
Glide 
    .with(context)   
    .loadFromMediaStore(uri).asBitmap().format(DecodeFormat.ALWAYS_ARGB_8888)
```

But the quality is always low.

Does anybody see where is my error??

Comment: add `.asIs()` for test case

Comment: Ever figure this out?  I just want it to load exactly as it would load in setImageResource without losing quality.

Comment: No man, unfortunately I don't! :(

Answer (score 0):

Instead of calling

`.diskCacheStrategy(DiskCacheStrategy.SOURCE)`

try

`.diskCacheStrategy(DiskCacheStrategy.RESOURCE)`

Comment: I'm using Glide 3.8 so there is no DiskCacheStrategy.RESOURCE. Anyway I tried using any DiskCacheStrategy and no one slved my issue :(